# Truncate/Convert Datacolumn Dates. C# Console App

Tags: c#

I have ODBC DSN connection that I bring into DataTable. Column Three is populated with TIMESTAMP data.

I have...

```
BRANCH----| TYPE-----| ID

1---------------| R-----------| 14/03/2013 9:42
1---------------| R-----------| 9/01/2015 9:42
3---------------| W-----------| 13/09/2014 9:42
2---------------| R-----------| 1/03/2012 9:42
```

I want to see:

```
1---------------| R-----------| 03/2013
1---------------| R-----------| 01/2015
3---------------| W-----------| 09/2014
2---------------| R-----------| 03/2012
```

I have used the code below before to truncate data. However I cant make it work in this case due to type mismatch.

Any pointers would be great.

```
dcUnits.Expression = string.Format
  ("SUBSTRING({0}, 1, 1)+''+{1}+''+{2}", "BRANCH", "TYPE", "ID");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply [YearMonth standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#YearMonth) to the column. The "Y" or "y" standard format specifier represents a custom date and time format string that is defined by the DateTimeFormatInfo.YearMonthPattern property of a specified culture. For example, the custom format string for the invariant culture is "yyyy MMMM".

This is just an idea which might work for you.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo myDTFI = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).DateTimeFormat;
DateTime myDT = new DateTime(ID);
dcUnits.Expression = string.Format
("SUBSTRING({0}, 1, 1)+''+{1}+''+{2}", "BRANCH", "TYPE", myDT.ToString("y", myDTFI));
```

Comment: That is great, do you know how i can incorporate that into my code like the example expression? I am ok with formatting individual variables but lost when it comes to fomatting a column.

Comment: yes, that is the name of the column for the timestamps.  thanks :)

Comment: Please check if that works for you. This is just an **idea**

Comment: That looks really good. I have an issue compiling as i get "The name 'ID' does not exist in the current context' I will keep working on it. I must be missing something. The error is in this section - DateTime(ID);